# Python 3.3 - Lists

Tags: python

So I'm trying to create a state abbreviation list of the first 10 states. Easy enough (lest call this list states1). Then I want to create a second list using slicing where is only outputs the middle 4 states...still enough enough(we'll call this list states2). Ok so the part I'm getting messed up on is I here.. I want to use a function (lets just name it list_func) with the states2 being the only argument. Within this argument I want to delete the second state in the list, insert TX as index 2, ask the user for a random new state and append that to the list, then reverse the list. Here what I've come up with so far.. I think I have most of it correct but I'm not sure on the fine tuning...

```
def main():

    states1 = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL']
    print(states1)
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    print(states2)

    for list_func in states2:
        states2.remove('CA')
        states2.insert(1,'TX')
        user_st = input('Enter a new state: ')
        states2.append(user_st)
        states2.reverse()

    print(states2)


main()
```

Comment: For that matter, `list_func` doesn't appear to even _be_ a function, before we even mention the fact no one is calling it.

Comment: Should be printing `states2` not your iterator, `list_func`... and I don't see any need for a `for` loop over `states2`.

Comment: You should consider a better title, for the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints of the problem, something like this would work:

```
def main():
    states1 = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL']
    print(states1)
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    print(states2)

    list_func(states2)


def list_func(states):
    states.remove('CA')
    states.insert(1,'TX')
    user_st = input('Enter a new state: ')
    states.append(user_st)
    states.reverse()

    print(states)

main()
```

list_func is now a function, the sole  input being the states2 list. When that function is called, it will do the things you listed. Did not use pop() as you mentioned you have not covered it yet

Comment: Oh I see... so we need to call the list_func within the main to make it work. But I also need to define it to make it work... Awesome!! TY!!

Answer (score -1):

Should be printing `states2` not your iterator, `list_func`... and I don't see any need for a `for` loop over `states2`.

```
def main():

    states1 = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL']
    print(states1)
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    print(states2)

    states2.remove('CA') 
    states2.insert(1,'TX')
    user_st = input('Enter a new state: ')
    states2.append(user_st)
    states2.reverse()

    print(states2)
```

Consider using `pop` method instead of `remove` which could be done like:

```
states2.pop(states2.index('CA'))
```

For your homework assignment:

```
states1 = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL']
print(states1)
states2 = states1[3:7]
print(states2)

# call your function:
list_func(states2)
print(states2)



def list_func(lst):
    lst.pop(lst.index('CA')
    lst.insert(1,'TX')
    user_st = input('Enter a new state: ')
    lst.append(user_st)
    lst.reverse
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this at first but it just didn't look right to me for some reason because my instruction said to "execute a function named list_func with states2 as its sole argument"

Comment: Cheers, sometimes you just need another set of eyes to look at the problem. In any case, you might want to consider `pop` instead of `remove`.

Comment: So I've been told.. but we haven't gotten to that part in the book yet, lol.I'm still not sure what the instructions meant when it said: "execute a function named list_func with states2 as its sole argument"

Comment: See revision which includes a function `list_func` which takes a list as its sole argument.